# Issue when generating fillable PDF in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fillable

I want generate a pdf file to the customer that can edit it and then download it, 
I use Laravel 8, mpdf 0.8.15, niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf 4.1 and  php 7.4 
I tried this code with mpdf package in controller :

```
    $html = file_get_contents(resource_path('views/app/pdf/inventory/inventory2.blade.php'));
     $pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

        $pdf = Mpdf::loadView('app.pdf.inventory.inventory2');
        $pdf->useActiveForms = true;

        $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
       return $pdf->Output(); 
      // return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
```

The view was rendred with blade syntax `{{ }}` `@if...` , so it's not useful 
also I tried `niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf` that can load view not write html content, but the pdf generated was not fillable, It create the form staticly (input, buttons ...) not editale 
have you an idea to get a fillable pdf ?

Comment: If this is within a Laravel controller class, you can change your top line to `$html = view('app.pdf.inventory.inventory2')->render();` which will render the HTML without the blade syntax. It may work then? I'm not 100% sure if it will be editable within the .pdf though.

Comment: @GaryThomas Yes it works thank you so much, and the pdf is editable, just no I will fix css and action form